# "1 days" should be "1 day" in the "You reached your question limit" page

Tags: bug

I'm currently prevented from asking questions for 2 days as I've reached my question limit because I've asked two questions out of which one of them was a duplicate and the other has 3 downvotes and an upvote.

Quoting a small part from the "you reached the question limit" page which appears when I press the <kbd>Ask Question</kbd> button:

> It's been 1 days since you asked your last question. We ask that you wait 2 days before asking again. Use this time to revisit your previous questions, editing to address any issues that folks have pointed out in comments.

The mistake here is "1 days". It should be "1 day". This is a minor bug and needs to be fixed. Also,shouldn't "ask" be "request" or something similar?

Answer (score -1):

As this is an Stack Exchange software issue rather than a Puzzling.SE issue, you may find a better answer/response on the main [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) site. While the devs do look at smaller meta sites, it will probably get more immediate attention there. You can see similar pluralization issues being noted in the past (with varying degrees of concern) with [this search.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbug%5D%20plural%20is%3Aquestion)

*However*, one common response is that this kind of thing is pretty trivial. Like you said, it's pretty minor. While they *usually* get fixed eventually, the first comment is normally some reference to this old tweet:

[image]

You have been warned :P

Comment: Is this issue present in all StackExchange sites? This is the first time I'm prevented from asking questions.....

Comment: While I haven't seen it myself, I'm sure it must be. I can't imagine that Puzzling.SE has customized the code that pluralizes this message.

Comment: I currently don't have an account in MSE,but would posting this on MSO help?(I already have an account in MSO plus I'll get a lot more attention there). Also, isn't it possible to migrate this question?

Comment: This is common to all sites, but reporting bugs on per-site metas is fine. No need to go elsewhere. (Although if you were to do so, Meta Stack Exchange would be the right place, not MSO.) (cc @CoolGuy)